# Passing values to include function inside range, using defaults with merge

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

Given this `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      {{- include "app.container" (merge .Values.app $) | nindent 8 }}
      {{- include "ports" (merge .Values.app ) | nindent 8 }}
      {{- range $k, $v := .Values.extraContainers }}
      {{- $nameDict := dict "name" $k -}}
        {{- include "app.container" (mustMergeOverwrite $.Values.app $nameDict $v)  | nindent 8 }}
        {{- include "ports" (merge $nameDict $v ) | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

This helpers file...

```
{{/* vim: set filetype=helm: */}}

{{/*
app container base
*/}}
{{- define "app.containerBase" -}}
- name: {{ .name | default "app" }}
  image: {{ .image.name }}:{{ .image.tag }}
  {{- if .command }}
  command:
    {{- range .command }}
    - {{ . | quote }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if .args }}
  args:
    {{- range .args }}
    - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
    {{- range .envVars }}
    - name: {{ .name }}
      {{- with .value }}
      value: {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .valueFrom }}
      valueFrom:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- if or .Values.configMaps .Values.secrets .Values.configMapRef }}
  envFrom:
    {{- if .Values.configMaps }}
    - configMapRef:
        name: "{{- include "app.fullname" $ }}"
    {{- end }}
    {{- range .Values.configMapRef }}
    - configMapRef:
        name: {{ . }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- range $name, $idk := $.Values.secrets }}
    - secretRef:
        name: "{{- include "app.fullname" $ }}-{{ $name }}"
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end -}}

{{/*
app container
*/}}
{{- define "app.container" -}}
{{- include "app.containerBase" . }}
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: {{ .resources.limits.cpu | default "100m" | quote }}
      memory: {{ .resources.limits.memory | default "128Mi" | quote }}
      {{- if .resources.limits.ephemeralStorage }}
      ephemeral-storage: {{ .resources.limits.ephemeralStorage }}
      {{- end }}
    requests:
      cpu: {{ .resources.requests.cpu | default "100m" | quote }}
      memory: {{ .resources.requests.memory | default "128Mi" | quote }}
      {{- if .resources.requests.ephemeralStorage }}
      ephemeral-storage: {{ .resources.requests.ephemeralStorage }}
      {{- end }}
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: {{ .securityContext.runAsUser }}
    runAsGroup: {{ .securityContext.runAsGroup }}
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
{{- end -}}

{{/*
ports
*/}}
{{- define "ports" -}}
{{- if .port }}
  ports:
  - containerPort: {{ .port }}
  protocol: {{ .protocol | default "tcp" | upper }}
  {{- range .extraPorts}}
    - containerPort: {{ required ".port is required." .port }}
    {{- if .name }}
      name: {{ .name }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if .protocol }}
      protocol: {{ .protocol | upper }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

This values.yaml

```
extraContainers:
  extra-container2:
    image:
      name: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foobar-two
      tag: test
    command:
      - sleep
      - 10
    envVars:
      - name: FOO
        value: BAR
    probes:
      readinessProbe:
        path: /ContainerTwoReadinessPath
      livenessProbe:
        path: /ContainerTwoLivenessPath
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 200Mi
        memory: 2Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 200Mi
        memory: 2Gi
  extra-container3:
    image:
      name: xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foobar-three
      tag: latest
    command:
      - sleep
      - 10
    envVars:
      - name: FOO
        value: BAZ
    probes:
      readinessProbe:
        enabled: false
      livenessProbe:
        enabled: false

app:
  image:
    name: xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foobar
    tag: latest
  probes:
    readinessProbe:
      path: /_readiness
      enabled: true
    livenessProbe:
      path: /_liveness
      enabled: true
  port: 100
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100Mi
      memory: 1Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 100Mi
      memory: 1Gi
```

Why does `helm template`  result in the below:

```
---
# Source: corp-service/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foobar:latest
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "100Mi"
              memory: "1Gi"
            requests:
              cpu: "100Mi"
              memory: "1Gi"
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 2000
            runAsGroup: 2000
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        
          ports:
          - containerPort: 100
          protocol: TCP
        - name: extra-container2
          image: xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foobar-two:test
          command:
            - "sleep"
            - "10"
            - name: FOO
              value: "BAR"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "200Mi"
              memory: "2Gi"
            requests:
              cpu: "200Mi"
              memory: "2Gi"
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 2000
            runAsGroup: 2000
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        
        - name: extra-container3
          image: xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foobar-three:latest
          command:
            - "sleep"
            - "10"
            - name: FOO
              value: "BAZ"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "200Mi"
              memory: "2Gi"
            requests:
              cpu: "200Mi"
              memory: "2Gi"
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 2000
            runAsGroup: 2000
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

i.e why does `extra-container3` have `resources:` set with values from `extra-container2` instead of taking them from the default set of resources found under `.values.app`.

essentially, i want `extracontainers` to use default values from `.values.app` unless i explicitly set them inside the `extracontainers` section. however it seems that if a previous iteration of the loop over `extracontainers` defines some values, they are used in the next iteration if they are not overriden.

the resources for extra-container3 i am expecting are:

```
resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100Mi
      memory: 1Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 100Mi
      memory: 1Gi
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your cited code dies evaluating `{{ .securityContext.runAsGroup }}` which is simple enough to fix but I really, really want to draw your attention to the word *minimal* in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because narrowing down the question helps us both, since it helps you find the _exact not-working thing_ and helps us by not having 800,000 irrelevant details to wade through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a couple of things going on here, but mostly the answer is that `(mergeMustOverwrite)` **mutates** the `$dest` map, which causes your range to "remember" the last value it saw, which according to your question isn't the behavior you want. The simplest answer is to use `(deepCopy $.Values.app)` as the `$dest`, but there's an asterisk to that due to another bug we'll cover in a second

```
       {{- $nameDict := dict "name" $k -}}
-        {{- include "app.container" (mustMergeOverwrite $.Values.app $nameDict $v)  | nindent 8 }}
+        {{- include "app.container" (mustMergeOverwrite (deepCopy $.Values.app) $nameDict $v)  | nindent 8 }}
         {{- include "ports" (merge $nameDict $v ) | nindent 8 }}
       {{- end }}
```

You see, `(deepCopy $.Values.app)` stack-overflows `helm` because of your inexplicable use of `(merge .Values.app $)` drags in `Chart`, `Files`, `Capabilities` and the whole world. I'm guessing your `_helpers.tpl` must have been copy-pasted from somewhere else, which explains the erroneous *relative* `.Values` reference inside that `define`. One way to fix that is to remove the `.Values.configMaps`, so it will track the `.app` context like I expect you meant, or you can change the first `(merge)` to artificially create a `"Values": {}` item just to keep the template from blowing up when in tries to reference `.app.Values.configMaps`. The correct one will depend on what you were intending, but `(merge .Values.app $)` is almost certainly not it

so, either:

```
--- a/templates/_helpers.tpl
+++ b/templates/_helpers.tpl
@@ -28,13 +28,13 @@ app container base
         {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
       {{- end }}
     {{- end }}
-  {{- if or .Values.configMaps .Values.secrets .Values.configMapRef }}
+  {{- if or .configMaps .secrets .configMapRef }}
   envFrom:
-    {{- if .Values.configMaps }}
+    {{- if .configMaps }}
     - configMapRef:
         name: "{{- include "app.fullname" $ }}"
     {{- end }}
-    {{- range .Values.configMapRef }}
+    {{- range .configMapRef }}
     - configMapRef:
         name: {{ . }}
     {{- end }}
```

*or*

```
       containers:
-      {{- include "app.container" (merge .Values.app $) | nindent 8 }}
+      {{- include "app.container" (merge .Values.app (dict "Values" (dict))) | nindent 8 }}
       {{- include "ports" (merge .Values.app ) | nindent 8 }}
```